# Using .gitignore to prevent branch misuse

Tags: git

In the context of a project being managed with git and consisting in a master branch and various derived branches, one of the developers has proposed to use the .gitignore file to prevent accidental modifications in some important files from the derived branches. Those "core" files should be modified from the "master" branch only (but they should be "visible" in the other branches, which only add/modify non-core files).

My question is: is there any drawback on adding the "core" files to the .gitignore file in each of the (non-master) branches? Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware that `.gitignore` only prevents files from being *initially added*. If you have files that are already being tracked, adding them to `.gitignore` won't do anything.

Comment: You can to setup pre-receive hooks... but "Enforcing this kind of thing on the git level might not be the best idea. Sending out an email to the team might work much better without polluting git repository with unnecessary restrictions." (c)@RuslanOsipov

Comment: @Chris "only prevents files from being initially added"... And that only half-heartedly - there's always `git add -f`... I'm not sure the OPs proposed workflow will really accomplish what is intended...

Comment: @twalberg, it's a good thing that `git add -f` exists, but you're right: `.gitignore` is useless in terms of enforcing access.

Comment: @Chris, I'm adding your answer (in the comments) as a Community Wiki answer, so I can close this issue (as suggested in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Chris:

> You should be aware that .gitignore only prevents files from being
>   initially added. If you have files that are already being tracked,
>   adding them to .gitignore won't do anything.